# CentOS can't boot because of iSCSIconnection not established

Tags: boot, iscsi, centos6.5

I have a CentOS 6.5 with a iSCSI disk connected.
This disk is mounted as partition.

Everything is working fine but after I tried to reboot, the system won't boot. 
It can't mount the partition /dev/sdc1 (the iSCSI disk). 
The system is asking me for the root password but once logged on, I'm in read-only, so I can't change the boot priority or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Boot from CD in rescue mode, mount root (`/`) partition and edit `/mountpoint/etc/fstab` file. (`/mountpoint` is the directory where you mount your root partition)

If you do not have CD follow those steps from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/117954/680869):

> 1. Shutdown the computer
> 2. Boot into Recovery Mode --After BIOS load, hold down Shift key to
>      access the grub menu --Once in grub menu, select the entry ending in
>      "(recovery mode)"
> 3. From the next menu selected option to enter Root Session
> 4. At the root session, execute command `mount -o rw,remount /` to
>      remount the filesystem as read-write

and then edit `/etc/fstab`

Comment: t's a VM and the CD is disabled. And given that I can only log in read only I can't modify anything.

Comment: @RobinMULA, check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

iSCSI partitions should use the `_netdev` mount option to avoid a mount attempt prior network activation.

From `man mount`:

```
_netdev
The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).
```

At the point of failing the system is probably not live and likely in the initramfs stage. To recover check with `mount` if the root partition is mounted somewhere. On Cent OS 7 the path should be in `/sysroot`, not quite sure where Cent OS 6 has the partition mounted.
Once found, edit `<rootprefix>/etc/fstab` and add the `_netdev` option to the according iSCSI entry.

Verify SELinux contexts of `<rootprefix>/etc/fstab` before/after activation (if enabled on the system). The context needs to be correct, otherwise rebooting will bring up different issues.

Reboot the system.